# How to show only filtered litst item in viewpager?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I populated a list view from a sqlite database table. Every table data item has a unique id 1 to n. Every list item has also a id as like table and they are same. When user click on list item I read item id then pass to view pager activity through intent. Then I read item from table where id= itemId. If I click next I read itemId++ for previous itemId--.

Now if I filtered(search in list) my list view may I found 3 item where id 2,7,10. If I click on first item i can read it and its ok but if i click next then item id of 3 will come but i need 7. How can I do it?

Comment: create a separate array to handle it, you can then use array [i] +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of ids to the viewpager .

Example

on a non-filtered click item the list would be (1,2,3)

on a filtered item click the list is (2,7,10)

and set :

getcount (list.size ())

every new page has the Id of list.get(position)